Can't boot from bootable USB when internal SSD connected
I'm trying to help a friend repair his computer that won't boot. There are 2 internal drives:

An internal SSD drive.
An internal hard drive.

The computer shows a splash screen with a spinning circle that goes forever. I can enter the BIOS and look at the boot priority.
I created a bootable Windows 10 USB drive to try and repair the windows install. The Windows install I'm trying to repair should be on the SSD, and indeed it looks like Windows Boot manager is on the Adata SSD when looking at the boot options.
With the internal drives disconnected, I am able to boot the bootable USB. With the SSD drive connected however, it will not boot from the bootable USB, even when manually selected as the boot option in the BIOS (DEL button) or manually selecting a boot option right after posting (F12). "Fast boot" is disabled in the BIOS and "CSM" is enabled. What else can I try?

Do understand you cannot repair Windows from outside of Windows? Once Windows cannot be accessed you’re likely going to have to perform a clean install. Was Windows installed in Legacy Mode? That’s the only reason I can think that CSM would be enabled.

It was my understanding you can repair a Windows install from a bootable Windows install on a USB drive. I have no idea how the original Windows was installed.

I have never in 20 years fixed a Windows installation that wasn’t bootable from outside of Windows once it could no longer boot, in every case, by the time it no longer booted it was a failed storage device. If you have no idea how Windows was booted then you’ll ha e to asked the owner of the device

Sure, I have never been successful either, but I thought I'd try. In any case even if I wanted to reinstall Windows I can't, since the computer won't boot into the bootable USB drive with the SSD connected. The owner of the device has no idea how these things work.
